# Форматирование даты в discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

При использовании **interaction.guild.createdAt**, выдаётся не тот формат даты, какой бы я хотел.

Код:

```
if (commandName === 'server') {
    await interaction.reply(`Создан: ${interaction.guild.createdAt}`);
```

Вывод: *Создан: Sun Jul 10 2022 02:28:54 GMT+0500 (Екатеринбург, стандартное время)*

Как можно изменить формат этой даты, к примеру в DD/MM/YYYY, чтобы вывод был Jul 10 2022?

Comment: Библиотеки типа date-fns или moment.js умеют парсить даты и форматировать. Вам нужно будет только извлечь непосредственно дату из строки.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно явно указать локаль и опции.

Вот так:

```js
let d  =  new Date();
   console.log(d.toLocaleDateString("en-Gb", {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'short',
    day: 'numeric',
   }))
```